# ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback taking too long

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback to receive notifications when my address book database changes.  My app allows users to edit a person's contact info.  However, it takes forever for the callback to be invoked.  For instance, in one case it 30 seconds.  I need it to happen immediately!  How do I go about doing this?  Has anyone else experienced this issue using ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback?

Comment: Please add some detail about the circumstances this behavior takes place in.

Comment: I'm using ABPersonViewController to edit a contact that's in a UITableView.  After I edit the contact and click "Done" and dismiss the popover which contains the ABPersonViewController, it takes about 30 seconds or so to have the callback invoked.

Comment: It's an external database; instead of waiting for the system to notify you why don't you just post a notification yourself?

Comment: I'd rather use the callback mechanism that's already in place to tell me when things have changed.  That's the reason it's there.  I don't think there's a clean way of checking if changes have occurred with the ABPersonViewController.

Comment: The problem is that the system controls that notification; it doesn't necessarily have to conform to your time scheme. Instead of doing key value observation or something on ABPersonViewController, just post a notification that the contact has been changed when you close the popover. That way you can control your own time scale instead of hoping the system conforms to your expectations.

Comment: I originally had this solution, but calling a notification every time the popover got dismissed led to some undesired behavior within my application.  I guess I'll go back to this solution and resolve those issues.  Although, if the callback occurred in a reasonable time it'd save me the trouble.